# MOV instruction size

Tags: assembly, x86

Can someone help me to find the size (length in bytes) of the following instructions? The instructions are on x86 on AI-32 machine:

```
mov (%rax),%rdi
mov %rsp,%rdx
```

Comment: What problem did you encounter when you assmebled this yourself?

Comment: I this makes sense now. I just need to know the size of the instruction.

Comment: Don't forget to credit SO for the answer when you turn in the assignment. Otherwise you are taking credit for someone else's work, which is plagiarism.

Comment: You are supposed to select D, "none of the above".  CPU registers whose name start with R are only available on a x64 processor.

Answer (score 4):

x86 is not `AI-32` but `IA-32`. And to find the length of any instruction just assemble it and check the output (if you don't want to lookup in Intel's manual and assemble the instruction yourself). You can use the [Online x86 / x64 Assembler and Disassembler](https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm#disassembly) for a quick check. It uses Intel syntax so you'll need to convert the above instructions to

```
mov rdi, [rax]
mov rdx, rsp
```

The output is

```
0:  48 8b 38                mov    rdi,QWORD PTR [rax]
3:  48 89 e2                mov    rdx,rsp
```

which means each instruction is 3-byte long

Answer (score 1):

Debug you application with 'step into', then you will see the dis-assembly info by which you will find the instruction size easily.

Answer (score -1):

The size is 8 bytes I believe.

Comment: That's the operand-size.